# Menu retracting when leaving initial menu button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So my menu navigation is set up like this:

- Menu buttons are inline-block divs, set to `float: left`
- When hovering over buttons, arrow selector appears
- When hovering over buttons with extra options (more menu), drop down menu appears
- As you move from button to button, arrows and drop-down disappear and reappear on currently selected button

Now, the problem lies with the retracting of the menus. I cannot seem to get the menus to stay open (and not retract) when moving down and leaving the buttons. The current setup uses `$.hover()` to animate the selector arrows as well as the drop-down.

Is using the `$.hover()` the proper way to accomplish this? If not how can it be coded to avoid the drop-down retraction?

**EDIT** I removed all code in my fiddle pertaining to keeping the menu expanded. I did this because none of my code worked..

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav">

    <div id="home" class="button selected">Home
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="mine" class="button">My Account
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="course" class="button">Courses
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="cal" class="button">Calendar
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="contact" class="button">Contact
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="selBar">
        <div id="home_opt" class="box_opt"></div>
        <div id="mine_opt" class="box_opt"></div>
        <div id="course_opt" class="box_opt"></div>
        <div id="cal_opt" class="box_opt"></div>
        <div id="contact_opt" class="box_opt"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div, p, span {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto
}
#nav {
    width: 500px;
    height: 75px;
    position: relative;
}
.button {
    background: #000;
    color: #00A3EF;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 48px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 14px solid #bfefff;
    border-left: 14px solid transparent;
    border-right: 14px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 12px;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#selBar {
    background: #bfefff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 18px;
    z-index: -1
}
.box_opt {
    background: #bfefff;
    width: 100px;
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    bottom: -80%;
}
.selected {
    background: #333333;
}
.button:hover {
    background: #4c4c4c;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.button').click(function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    $('.selected').each(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    });
    target.toggleClass("selected");
});

$('.button').hover(function () {
    var link,
    classLink,
    linker = "_opt";

    $(this).children(".arrow").css("z-index", "0");
    link = $(this).attr("id");
    switch (link) {
        case 'home':
            break;
        case 'mine':
            classLink = "#" + link + linker;
            expandBar(0);
            break;
        case 'course':
            expandBar(1);
            break;
        case 'cal':
            expandBar(2);
            break;
        case 'contact':
            expandBar(3);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}, function () {
    console.log("button left");
    $('.arrow').css("z-index", "-1");
    $('.box_opt').css("height", "10px");
});

function expandBar(start) {
    var childIndex = "#selBar div:gt(" + start + ")";
    $(childIndex).css("height", "100px");
}
```

Thank you for any and all help.

JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vulpCod3z/4kLR4/)

Comment: You need to add the hover thing on the sub elements of your menu.
As I see your code I can't find anything doing so.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? I'm more of a visual learner, so it helps to have an fiddle or some code examples.

Comment: I haven't managed to get it work with your actual code.
I'll try another fiddle.
Basically, your hovering works when you are hovering the class .button, but nothing says "still hovering when i'm on the sub menu"

Comment: Was `.hover()` a bad choice? Should I use normal mouse events instead?

Comment: JQuery is fine. Once you get to JQuery, it can be tricky to use normal javascript too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a nice weekend, I was able to fix my problem. It called for rewriting the html (as much as I didn't want to) and now it works great. @user1835565 and @Sjors van Dongen, thanks for your helpful input. It helped to direct me in the right path :)

So, the html structure now goes: `#nav -> ._butt -> ._menu -> ._arrow`

The hover event on the buttons sends the button, and a selector (hover or not) to functions.
The functions then take the element and get the children (the menu, arrows).
Lastly it adds (or removes) classes based on the selector data.

tldr; Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vulpCod3z/TAxv6/1/), check it out.

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">

    <div id="home" class="_butt">Home
        <div class="_noMenu _endLeft">
            <div class="_arrow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="mine" class="_butt">My Account
        <div class="_menu">
            <div class="_arrow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="course" class="_butt">Courses
        <div class="_menu">
            <div class="_arrow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="cal" class="_butt">Calendar
        <div class="_noMenu">
            <div class="_arrow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="contact" class="_butt">Contact
        <div class="_noMenu _endRight">
            <div class="_arrow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
p, span, div {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

._butt {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #000;
    color: #00A3EF;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 48px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

._butt:hover {
    background: #4c4c4c;
}

._arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: #bfefff solid 18px;
    border-right: transparent solid 18px;
    border-left: transparent solid 18px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 9px;
    z-index: -1;
}

._show {
    z-index: 1
}

._dropShow {
    margin: 0;
    left: 32px;
    z-index: 1
}

._menu {
    width: inherit;
    height: 10px;
    background: #bfefff;
}

._noMenu {
    width: inherit;
    height: 10px;
    background: #bfefff;
}

._endLeft {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}

._endRight {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}

.hoverIt {
    animation: drop .3s;
    -webkit-animation: drop .3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}



@keyframes drop {
    from { height: 10px; }
    to { height: 100px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes drop {
    from { height: 10px; }
    to { height: 100px; }
}
```

**JS**

```
$('._butt').hover( function(e) { menuSelect( e.target, 1 ) }, function(e) { menuSelect( e.target, 0 ) });

function menuSelect( tar, sel ) {
    var thisButt = $(tar);
    if( thisButt.children( "._menu" ) ) {
        thisMenu = thisButt.children( "._menu" ),
        thisArrow = thisMenu.children( "._arrow" );
        if( sel == 1 ) {
            thisMenu.addClass( "hoverIt _endLeft _endRight" );
            thisArrow.addClass( "_dropShow" );
            dropMenu( thisButt, 1 );
        }
        if( sel == 0 ) {
            thisMenu.removeClass( "hoverIt _endLeft _endRight" );
            thisArrow.removeClass( "_dropShow" );
            dropMenu( thisButt, 0 );
        }
    }
    if( thisButt.children( "._noMenu" ) ) {
        thisMenu = thisButt.children( "._noMenu" );
        thisArrow = thisMenu.children( "._arrow" );
        if( sel == 1) {
            thisArrow.addClass( "_show" );
        }
        if( sel == 0 ) {
            thisArrow.removeClass( "_show" );
        }
    }
}

function dropMenu( par, sel ) {
    var def_butt = 100,
        _buttIndex = 5,
        ch = par.children();
    if( sel == 1 ) {
        if( ch.hasClass( "_menu" ) ) {
            var chIndex = par.prevAll().length;
            ch.css( "width", (_buttIndex - chIndex) * def_butt );
        }
    }
    if( sel == 0 ) {
        ch.css( "width", def_butt );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have what you want by checking what the element is the user has hovered.
Using `e.target` which specifies the element

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MrAtiebatie/XWPxw/24/)

Comment: Not working properly when you hover from one to another menu item.

Comment: This works but it has the same problem that I ran into earlier: it doesn't remove the arrows from previous buttons as you move around.

Comment: You must tag the element you are currently hovering!
So you always remove the arrow when hover is triggered on ALL elements and add it on the one actually being hovered.
If the element is identified, then you can place the arrow on it.
The whole process must be rewritten, it's a bit messy. I advise to call actual functions and not anonymous functions.

Comment: It's ok, I relinked the base fiddle. Also, @1835565 thanks for the input. I will be working to rewrite this, and will post a new link when a solution is completed.